# Regex for strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of strings and need to return substrings from them

The output should replace occurrences of

```
Test: intervening text - Exists
```

with

```
intervening text
```

I've tried:

```js
const inputs = [
  'Test: Text - N GTTTsds - Exists',
  'Test: Text something here - Exists',
  'Tictactoe foo baz - bar - Exists',
  'Something still here',
  'Joe Doe'
];
const output = [];

inputs.forEach(input => {
  const resp = /(?:Test: )?(.+)(- Exists)?/.exec(input);
  output.push(resp);
});
console.log(output);
```

but it doesn't produce the expected output of:

```
[
    "Text - N GTTTsds", 
    "Text something here", 
    "Tictactoe foo baz - bar"
    'Something still here',
    'Joe Doe'
]
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: The second input string only contains `Exist` (without the `s` at the end). Was that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex with anchors and lazy quantifier:

```
/^(?:Test: )?(.+?)(?: - Exists?)?$/;
```

Also you need to grab first capture group from resulting array.

```js
const inputs = [
 'Test: Text - N GTTTsds - Exists',
 'Test: Text something here - Exist',
 'Tictactoe foo baz - bar - Exists',
 'Something still here',
 'Joe Doe'
];
const output = [];
const re = /^(?:Test: )?(.+?)(?: - Exists?)?$/;
var resp;

inputs.forEach(input => {
 resp = re.exec(input);
 if (resp != null && resp.length > 1)
  output.push(resp[1]);
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just replace them?

```js
const inputs = [
 'Test: Text - N GTTTsds - Exists',
 'Test: Text something here - Exist',
 'Tictactoe foo baz - bar - Exists',
 'Something still here',
 'Joe Doe'
];
const output = inputs.map(input => input.replace(/(^Test:)|(- Exist(s?)$)/g, '').trim());

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `Test` in one iteration and `- Exists` in another.

```js
const input = [
 'Test: Text - N GTTTsds - Exists',
 'Test: Text something here - Exist',
 'Tictactoe foo baz - bar - Exists',
 'Something still here',
 'Joe Doe'
];

const output = input.map(s => s.replace(/Test:\s+/g, '').replace(/\ -\ Exists?/g,  ''));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution: Force the Regex to match the start and the end of each string (`^` and `$`) and make the quantifier for arbitrary characters in the middle lazy by appending an `?`.

```js
const inputs = [
  'Test: Text - N GTTTsds - Exists',
  'Test: Text something here - Exist',
  'Tictactoe foo baz - bar - Exists',
  'Something still here',
  'Joe Doe'
];
const output = [];

inputs.forEach(input => {
  const resp = /^(?:Test: )?(.+?)(- Exists)?$/.exec(input);
  output.push(resp);
});
console.log(output);
```